# Получить значения input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить значения двух текстовых полей при событии change, со следующей структурой в документе. Таких блоков будет много на странице, так как блок создается динамически.

```
<div class="block">
    <span>Start</span><input class="start dt" type="text" name="start[]" readonly >
    <span>End</span><input class="end dt" type="text" name="end[]" readonly >
    <span class="count_day">1</span>
</div>
```

......

```
$((document).on('change', '.start', function (obj) {
    //obj[0].value - получаю только 1 input
   ......
});

$(document).on('change', '.end', function () {
    .......
});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()`, `$(this).next().val()`, `$(this).prev().val()`

Comment: next не работает, так как это будет span

Comment: работает. Все зависит от элемента к которому вы его применяете

Comment: Решил проблему таким образом:  $(this).parent().find('.start').val(), $(this).parent().find('.end').val()

Comment: да, вполне вариант, так как, я подозреваю, обработчики будут одинаковыми их можно в один селектор собрать `'.start, .end'`

Comment: да верно, спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

```
$((document).on('change', '.start, .end', function ) {
   var t1 = $(this).parent().find('.start').val();
   var t2 = $(this).parent().find('.end').val();
});
```